# How to enable front-channel or back-channel logout in identityserver4

Tags: identityserver4

I'm looking at how to disconnect the user currently logged on the mvc client (e.g. http://localhost:5001), when that user performs logout on identity server's deployment (e.g. http://localhost:5000)

I understand there's an implementation of OAuth2 in identityserver4 that does just that (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html and https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html)

Luckily for me, Brock Allen just pushed a change in the samples less than a day ago: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/issues/197

However the sample is either incomplete at this point, or I'm missing something.

on my server, I'm setting the value of FrontChannelLogoutUrl to http://localhost:5001/frontchannello, and I added that piece of code to my mvc client (basically stolen from the sample):

```
[HttpGet("frontChannello")]
public IActionResult FrontChannelLogout(string sid)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var currentSid = User.FindFirst("sid")?.Value ?? "";
        if (string.Equals(currentSid, sid, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            //await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            return new SignOutResult(new[] { "Cookies", "oidc" });
        }
    }

    return NoContent();
}
```

That code never gets called.

So my question is: should I use backchannel or frontchannel; and, how to implement it

Answer (score 2):

The [Identity server 4 documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signout.html) describes well how front-channel logout should be implemented. Look for the Quickstart [*8_AspnetIdentity*](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/master/Quickstarts/8_AspNetIdentity) as it provides most of the code required for the implementation.

Some highlights of the code required in the identity server :

In the [`AccountController.cs`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/master/Quickstarts/8_AspNetIdentity/src/IdentityServerAspNetIdentity/Quickstart/Account), the Logout function builds a `LoggedOutViewModel` and returns a `LoggedOut` view.

> ```
> [HttpPost]
> [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
> public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutInputModel model)
> {
>    // build a model so the logged out page knows what to display
>    var vm = await BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(model.LogoutId);
>    ...
>    return View("LoggedOut", vm);
> }
> ```

The SignOutIframeUrl iframe is served in the [`LoggedOut.cshtml`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/master/Quickstarts/8_AspNetIdentity/src/IdentityServerAspNetIdentity/Views/Account/LoggedOut.cshtml).

> ```
> @model LoggedOutViewModel
>
> <div class="page-header logged-out">
>    <small>You are now logged out</small>
>    ...
>    @if (Model.SignOutIframeUrl != null)
>    {
>        <iframe width="0" height="0" class="signout" src="@Model.SignOutIframeUrl"></iframe>
>    }
> </div>
> ```

What remains to be done is defining the `FrontChannelLogoutUri` for your each of your clients. That's normally done in the identity server's `config.cs`

> ```
>  public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
>  {
>         return new List<Client>
>         {
>             // resource owner password grant client
>             new Client
>             {
>                 ClientId = "js",
>                 ClientName = "JavaScript Client",
>                 AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
>                 RequirePkce = true,
>                 RequireClientSecret = false,
>
>                 RedirectUris =           { "http://localhost:5003/callback.html" },
>                 PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5003/index.html" },
>                 FrontChannelLogoutUri = "http://localhost:5003/frontChannello"
> ```

Comment: This mostly works but its calling the logout on the app i just logged out from and not the other clients.  Still trying to figure out why

Comment: @DaImTo According to their specification, your app should technically not be performing signout, your app should just redirect to the end-session endpoint of IS and then it will prompt the user for logout, if you added the id_token hint it can auto logout. IS keeps tracks of which apps the user navigated to, it will create an iframe for every frontchannellogoutIURi that was configured for clients the user navigated to, same for backchannel. So Is will trigger your signout endpoint for you.

Read the bottom section http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signout.html

Comment: Aspnetidentity quickstart linked above moved to : https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity

Answer (score 1):

Ok pretty simple. In your Logout action on the account controller (in idserver), make sure you display the LoggedOut view, which in turn shows the iFrame that calls the callback on the mvc client. Pretty much what the spec are saying.

Comment: But this only gives _one_ URL (and the value doesn't even come from `FrontChannelLogoutUri` or `BackChannelLogoutUri`). Therefore it can only sign out of one client -- not all of them.